# ViewState is loaded, in which Page Life Cycle Event in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net

ViewState is loaded, in which Page Life Cycle Event?
ViewState is loaded, in which Page Life Cycle Event?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewState is being loaded during the **Load** stage of the page life-cycle by [LoadViewState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.loadviewstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_LoadViewState_System_Object_) method on postback event only. Please see a detailed article from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)).